# created vf page used pageblock table in it also used custom controller but unable to display the list of records

Tags: apex, visualforce

this is the code for vf:

```
<apex:page Controller="UpdatingTheRecord">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock Id="GG">
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mycar}" var="ca">
     <apex:column HeaderValue="Car">
     <apex:commandLink value="{!ca.Name}" action="{!RecordId}" >    
     <apex:param value="{!ca.id}" name="id1"  assignTo="{!id1}"/>
       </apex:commandlink>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column value="{!ca.name}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!ca.Price__c}"/>

       <apex:outputField value="{!mycar.Price__c}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>            
   </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller code:

```
public with sharing class UpdatingTheRecord {
 public car__c mycar{get;set;}
public string id1{get;set;}

public UpdatingTheRecord(){
 list<car__c> mycar=new list<car__c>();
 mycar = [select Name, Price__c from car__c];
}

public PageReference RecordId() {
       //system.debug('id:valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee::::'+id1);
    PageReference pr = new PageReference ('/'+id1);
    return pr;        
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mycar variable outside updatingtherecord method, is not being populated. Try this.

```
public with sharing class UpdatingTheRecord {
public list<car__c> mycar{get;set;}
public string id1{get;set;}

public UpdatingTheRecord(){
 mycar=new list<car__c>();
 mycar = [select Name, Price__c from car__c];
}

public PageReference RecordId() {
       //system.debug('id:valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee::::'+id1);
    PageReference pr = new PageReference ('/'+id1);
    return pr;        
}

}
```